# Como formatar campos de dinheiro no django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-admin

Tenho um campo no meu Django admin que recebe um valor em reais, porém eu gostaria que esse valor ficasse formatado e não recebesse mais que duas casas decimais.

tentei usar um javascript pra modificar a pagina do django admin, mas isso gera muitos side effects:

```js
let valor = document.querySelector('#id_valor');
        let oldVal = '';
        valor.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
            let parts = this.value.split('.');
            console.log(parts)
            if (parts && parts[1] && parts[1].length > 3)
                this.value = oldVal;
                oldVal = this.value;
        });
```

Existe alguma maneira melhor de fazer isso no django?

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo, no próprio model vc poderia fazer isso

```
dinheiro = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

caso o usuário coloque 3 casas ou mais, aparece mensagem de erro informando a quantidade máxima de casas decimais que se pode usar.

Comment: Eu já tenho esse decimal_places ativo, eu gostaria que  o usuário não conseguisse digitar mais casas decimais, para que ele nem chegue a ver esse erro.

Comment: Tenta usar esse plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin